# Diameter of a compact is on boundary?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $ V $ be a normed vector space and let $ S $ be a compact subset of $ V $ and let $ a=sup(\|x-y\|)_{x,y \in S} $

I would like to know if it it true that exist $ x_0,y_0 \in \delta S $, boundary of $ S $, such that $ a=\|x_0-y_0\| $

Comment: How do you define the boundary of $S$?

Comment: i consider $ S $ as  topological space so it is the closure of $ S  $ without the interior of $ S $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are $x_0,y_0\in S$ with $\|x_0-y_0\| = a$. <sup>1</sup>

If now $x_0\notin\partial S$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset S$. This yields $x_0+ \delta(x_0-y_0)\in S$ for sufficiently small $\delta>0$. But then $$a\geq \|y_0-(x_0+\delta(x_0-y_0))\| = (1+\delta)\|y_0-x_0\| = (1+\delta)a > a,$$ which is a contradiction, so we must have $x_0\in\partial S$. Then of course $y_0\in\partial S$ aswell with the same proof.

<sup>1</sup>The function $S^2\to\mathbb R, (x,y)\mapsto \|x-y\|$ is continuous and therefore attains its maximum on the compact set $S^2$.

Comment: Thanks so much @LeBtz , exhaustive explanation.